# What is faster: Just set ImageView.setImageBitmap or check if ImageView already has this Bitmap attached?

Tags: android, caching, bitmap, android-resources, android-drawable

I've got a custom Image-cache which basically does the following:

I call it like this:

```
myImageLoader.imageForImageView(R.id.image_I_want_to_assign, myImageView);
```

With the method:

```
public void imageForImageView(int id, ImageView iv){
    Bitmap bitmap = cachedBitmaps.get(id);

    // Does this Bitmap already exist in the HashMap?
    if(bitmap != null)
        // If the given ImageView isn't null
        if(iv != null)
            // Then assign the Bitmap to the ImageView
            iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    // If it doesn't exists yet:
    else{
        // Create it locally using the BitmapFactory
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), id);
        // Does the Drawable with this given Resource-ID exist?
        // Yes:
        if(bitmap != null){
            // Put it in the HashMap
            cachedBitmaps.put(id, bitmap);
            // and assign it to the ImageView
            if(iv != null)
                iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            L.Log(TAG, "New Image added to the list: " + context.getResources().getResourceEntryName(id), LogType.INFO);
        }
        // No:
        else
            // Use the default Resource-ID instead
            if(iv != null)
                iv.setImageBitmap(cachedBitmaps.get(DEFAULT_CHECKBOX));
    }
}
```

My question is whether I should just keep:

```
if(bitmap != null)
    if(iv != null)
        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Or check if this ImageView doesn't already have this Bitmap attached, and if not add it:

```
if(bitmap != null)
    if(iv != null && ((BitmapDrawable)iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap() != bitmap)
        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

What is faster? Checking if the ImageView already had this Bitmap by using `getDrawable().getBitmap` including the BitmapDrawable cast, or just set it without checking even if it already had this same Bitmap as Image?

---

EDIT 1

If someone knows a way to check the time difference between the two options with some kind of UnitTest (10.000 times to prevent insecurities in the nano/microseconds) I would appreciate it. Or is there some kind of Debugger-style timer Eclipse-Plugin, so I can just set two timer-points (start and end) and it will give me a log of the time in between them?

Comment: So you don't know how to measure time between methods calls?

Comment: @Foxinsocks Nope, never used it. I guess I could start a timer after `if(bitmap != null)` and stop it again after `iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap)` both with and without the if, though I think that the mere nano/micro-seconds it will produce will vary too much. Is there a way to UnitTest this with for example calling it 10.000 times and then see the time-difference? How would you approach timing it?

Comment: Yes, you can do it. But this is another question. So either create new question or edit this one.